# У меня слова закодированы цифрами, как мне их конвертировать обратно, чтобы цифры соответствовали словам?

Tags: python

```
num = {0: 'blues', 1: 'classical', 2: 'country', 3: 'disco', 4: 'hiphop', 5: 'jazz', \
            6: 'metal', 7: 'pop', 8: 'reggae', 9: 'rock'}
```

```
i=0
A = []
while i < len(data_new):
  A.append(a)
  a =  np.argmax(prediction[0+i])
  i+=1
print(A)
```

```
[1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Откуда взялись переменные `data_new` и `prediction`? А по сути - пройдите циклом по списку и возьмите слова из вашего словаря по ключу, соответствующему элементу списка. Всё.

Comment: Эти переменные из кода  предыдущих строк они тут не играют роль, спасибо, получилось